# Import JavaScript file if internet is available

Tags: javascript, html

I’m new to HTML and JavaScript. I would like to import an external script file if internet is available.

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.1.3/firebase.js"></script>
```

Maybe it’s possible to import the online script in another script, with which I can check internet connection with `navigator.onLine`.

Comment: and what do you intend to do it the internet is down?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can check whether internet connection exist or not by using:

```
if (navigator.onLine)
 //returns true if internet connection available
 var s = document.createElement("script");
 s.type = "text/javascript";
 s.src = "http://somedomain.com/somescript";
 document.head.append(s);
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
if (navigator.onLine) {
    var scr = document.createElement('script');
    src.src = 'http://path.to/js.file';
    document.head.appendChild(scr);
} else
    alert('No connection!');
```